# BeanUtils copyProperties API to ignore null and specific propertie

Tags: java, spring, mapping, apache-commons-beanutils

Spring's `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` provides option to ignore specific properties while copying beans:

```
public static void copyProperties(Object source,
                 Object target,
                 String[] ignoreProperties) throws BeansException
```

Does the Apache Commons BeanUtils provide a similar feature?

Also is it possible to ignore null values while using Spring's `BeanUtils.copyProperties()`, I see this feature with Commons BeanUtils:

```
Date defaultValue = null;
DateConverter converter = new DateConverter(defaultValue);
ConvertUtils.register(converter, Date.class);
```

Can I achieve the same with Spring's BeanUtils?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to  ignore `null`-value you have to do it with the following line of code before copying properties:

```
BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getConvertUtils().register(false, false, 0);
```

Comment: What does the snippet do?

Comment: It seems that ConverterUtils does not support such register method (at least version 1.7.0)

Comment: Nope... it doesn't work and this answer lacks explanation.

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't work. The second flag should do it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Method .register(false, false, 0) doesn't exist

Comment: Could you please explain what this snippet does?

Answer (score 10):

In case you are using the `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils` you can ignore specific properies using the method `copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String... ignoreProperties)`. An example,

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(sourceObj, targetObj, "aProperty", "another");
```

Comment: This is not working with child properties, let's say i wanted to ignore all properties with name "id".

Comment: The question is not about ignoring child properties. If there are no questions about ignoring child properties then try to create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample code snippet which I am using for skip the null fields while copying to target. You can add checks for specific properties using property name, value etc. I have used org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils

```
public static void copyNonNullProperties(Object src, Object target) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, getNullPropertyNames(src));
}

public static String[] getNullPropertyNames(Object source) {
    final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
    PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

    Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
        Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
        if (srcValue == null)
            emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
    }
    String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
    return emptyNames.toArray(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Prajith's answer, here's one way in which I picked the property names with null values present in the source.

For some reason, I feel this is more readable.
You can choose to surround with try-catch or add throws at the method level.

```
public static void copyNonNullProperties(Object src, Object target) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, getNullPropertyNames(src));
}

public static String[] getNullPropertyNames(Object source) {
        List<String> nullValuePropertyNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field f : source.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                if (f.get(source) == null) {
                    nullValuePropertyNames.add(f.getName());
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return nullValuePropertyNames.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with BeansUtils in such way it will work for nested classes as well.

```
class NullAwareBeanUtilsBean extends BeanUtilsBean {
    
    
    @Override
    public void copyProperty(Object dest, String name, Object value)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if (value == null)
            return;
        else if(value instanceof NonNullCopy) {
            Class<?> destClazz = value.getClass();
                Class<?> origClazz = dest.getClass();
                String className = destClazz.getSimpleName();
        
                for(Method m : origClazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                    if(m.getReturnType().equals(destClazz)) {
                        copyProperties(m.invoke(dest, Collections.EMPTY_LIST.toArray()),value);
                    }                       
                }
                return;
        }

        super.copyProperty(dest, name, value);
    }

       
}
```

The complete explanation for the solution I have posted here:

[Copy non-null properties from one object to another using BeanUtils or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutils-or-similar)

Answer (score -1):

For ignoring null values:

```
BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getConvertUtils().register(false, false, 0);
```

For ignoring specific properties:

```
public static void copyProperties(Object source,
                              Object target,
                              String... ignoreProperties)
                       throws BeansException
```

documentation for ignoring properties: [Spring 4.1.0 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-)