# Parsing two objects into one

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I've two objects `objclient` and `objserver` of the same type `Object`,(i.e. Dog, Cat..)

when I receive `objclient` in my endpoint I need to replace its attributes with the non-null ones in `objserver` without doing explicitly, for example :

```
private void eraser(Object clientObject, Object serverObject){
  //set only non null attributes of serverObject to clientObject
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to do it does reflect.Field is the best choice ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy non-null properties from one object to another using BeanUtils or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutils-or-similar)

Comment: Another potential duplicate: [Helper in order to copy non null properties from object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301697/12567365) - not exactly your use-case, but very similar answers which could be adapted, I think. Bottom line: you can use reflection directly, but why not use a tested and widely used library which wraps it up for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) if you want to map values between different java objects without explicitly having to map every single field.

Answer (score 0):

**BeanUtils.copyProperties** is very common in spring-boot projects, we can use it with passing **ignoreProperties** (null case) & we can find the null case by using a custom method like below:

```
    private ClientObject eraser(ClientObject clientObject, ServerObject serverObject){
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(serverObject, clientObject, getNullPropertyNames(serverObject));
        return clientObject;
    }

    public static String[] getNullPropertyNames (Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

        Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for(java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
            Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
            if (srcValue == null) emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
        }

        String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
        return emptyNames.toArray(result);
    }
```

It will set only non null attributes of **serverObject** to **clientObject**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best solution comparing to @Rakib's one is:

```
private void erase(Object clientObject, Object defaultObject) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
            Field[] Fields = defaultObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        
            for (Field field : Fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = field.get(defaultObject);
                if(value !=null)
                    field.set(clientObject,value);
            }
    }
```