# What's the best approach to a partial update in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm learning Spring Boot and I'm trying to update an entity, but I really don't know how to do it in a proper way without many if statements.

This is my code:

*Update request* for the entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UpdatePlaceRequest {

    //nothing here is set as not null because we are not updating all the fields at once

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String country;

}
```

This is my *service*:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlaceService {

    private final PlaceRepository placeRepository;
    private final ProfileRepository profileRepository;
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    //...

    public PlaceResponse updatePlace(Long id, UpdatePlaceRequest updatePlaceRequest) {

        var place = placeRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Place not found"));


        //only update the fields that are not null

        return PlaceResponse.builder()
                   //other builder methods
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is my *controller*:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/places")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PlaceController {

    private final PlaceService placeService;

    //....

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PlaceResponse> updatePlace(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody                         UpdatePlaceRequest updatePlaceRequest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(placeService.updatePlace(id, updatePlaceRequest));
    }


}
```

I need something that looks good without if statements to checking every field

Comment: Not to defer you to another answer, but there are several great answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutils-or-similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy non-null properties from one object to another using BeanUtils or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutils-or-similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MapStruct` features to avoid boilerplate `if` statements - it allows to create a mapper which will map only not-null fields.

For your setup it could look like this:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING,
        nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface PlaceMapper {
    void updatePlacePartial(@MappingTarget Place placeEntity,
                            UpdatePlaceRequest updatePlaceRequest);
}
```

You could inject such `Mapper` as a bean in your service, pass your entity fetched by `findById()` method as a target, and your request DTO as a mapping source, and MapStruct will set only non-null fields from `UpdatePlaceRequest` to your entity.

Comment: Looks good and works like a charm, thanks